# Pinterest share button with Gridsome (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, pinterest, gridsome

i'm trying to add Pinterest share button on my page template. I've followed the guidelines of Pinterest by adding the script before the  tag, and the right  link in my page.

Both in development or production mode, the button is correctly updated by the script. But when i change page, and load another post, the button remains as "default", not updated.

working version (at first page load) :

[image: working version]

Non working version when I change page :

[image: non working version]

Pinterest script is (i think) loaded the way they ask on their website (before  tag) :

[image: script position]

and this is how i load it in metaInfo() :

[image: metaInfo loaded script]

i've tried everything, dynamically create script tag in mount cycle, with or without the button
i'm always facing this one shot working button, and i can't figure out why

the only strange thing i can see, is that i have this script in  : https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit_main.js?0.8287268902280864
script that i do not call in my template
but it's also present when the button is working

any help will be appreciated ;)

thanks

Comment: I would post this in the Gridsome Github Repository - I think there's something going on with how this is loading in, but it could also be tied to Vue-meta